# Class Hello in a test

Tags: java

I have come across this question in a test:

```
class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String hello = "Hello", lo = "lo";
        System.out.println(hello == ("Hel" + "lo"));
        System.out.println(hello == ("Hel" + lo));
        System.out.println(hello == ("Hel" + lo).intern());
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
true
false
true
```

Why is the second output `false`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it Comparision Literal Problem.

It Works.

```
System.out.print((hello.equals("Hel"+lo)) + " "); 
System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+"lo")) + " ");
```

Answer (score 5):

It prints 'false' because the concatenation of the String constant "Hel" and the String object 'lo' results in a seaparate, anonymous string object, with its own unique object reference. Thus, the "hello" String object and the concatenated string are different objects based on object reference (== operator, not by String value with String.equals()).

Answer (score 2):

`==` compares the references of two sides.

Here, for `hello == ("Hel"+lo)`, the references of two sides are not the same. So, it returns `false`.

For comparing values, use `equals()` method.

Comment: hello == ("Hel"+"lo") returns true

"concatenation of String literals happens at compile time and results in same object."

See link from @antonio's comment to the question

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because in the second output ("Hel" + lo) is no more in the string. The equality "==" operator compares object memory location and not characters of String.By default Java puts all string literal into string pool, but you can also put any string into pool by calling intern() method of java.lang.String class, like string created using new() operator.